# Django Form saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I would like to share with you my code in order to find a solution. I have a Django `form`. I would like to save data only if there is not another object with same data. In other words, objects should be unique.

If the object doesn't exist, I save it, else I display the form with an error message 'The object already exists with this features'.

This is my model:

```
def guide_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/guides/<guide_id>
    new_filename = f'guides/{instance.site.id}'
    if instance.profile_type:
        new_filename += f'_{instance.profile_type}'
    if instance.profile_level:
        new_filename += f'_{instance.profile_level}'
    if instance.language:
        new_filename += f'_{instance.language}'
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext:
        new_filename += ext

    return new_filename


class UserGuide(models.Model):
    """ A class for storing user guides depending on profiles """
    objects = models.Manager()

    site = models.ForeignKey(WebApplication, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='guides',
                             verbose_name=_('application'))
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name='file', upload_to=guide_path)
    profile_type = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('profile type'), choices=UserProfile.USER_TYPES, max_length=2,
                                    null=True, blank=True)
    profile_level = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('profile level'), choices=UserProfile.USER_ROLES, max_length=2,
                                     null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('language'), choices=settings.LANGUAGES, max_length=2, default='en')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user guide')
        verbose_name_plural = _('user guides')
        unique_together = ('site', 'profile_type', 'profile_level', 'language')
```

This is my form:

```
class UserGuideForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = UserGuide
        fields = ['site', 'file', 'profile_type', 'profile_level', 'language']
        widgets = {
            'file': CustomFileInput(attrs={'class': 'clearablefileinput'}),
        }
```

And this is my view:

```
class UserGuideUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """ Display a form to create a userguide

        **Context**

        ``subtitle``
            Title of the page

        **Template:**

        :template:`app/generic_form.html`
    """
    model = UserGuide
    form_class = UserGuideForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('userguide-list')
    template_name = 'app/form_userguide.html'
    permission_required = 'app.change_userguide'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(UserGuide, pk=pk)

    def get_title(self):
        return _('Edit user guide: ')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserGuideUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'subtitle': self.get_title(),
        })
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        site = form.cleaned_data['site']
        file = form.cleaned_data['file']
        profile_type = form.cleaned_data['profile_type']
        profile_level = form.cleaned_data['profile_level']
        language = form.cleaned_data['language']

        userguide = UserGuide.objects.filter(site=site.id, profile_type=profile_type, profile_level=profile_level, language=language)
        if userguide.exists():
            messages.error(self.request, _('A user guide for that profile and language already exists'))
            HttpResponseRedirect(self.template_name)
        else:
            pass
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

How I can add condition, if my object already exists, not save the form and return the form with the error message ?

Thank you

Comment: The form will already do that, because you defined `unique_together` on the model. There is no need for any of the code in `form_valid`.

Comment: I defined `unique_together`, but I can save object without errors even if another object exists with same data

Comment: @DanielRoseman If fields are `NULL`, I can save x time the same object. `unique_together` works if fields are not `NULL`

Comment: Also, don't set `null=True` on a `CharField`, it's bad practice (it allows for two "blank" types: empty string and null). But since `language` and `site` cannot be null, how could you save with null fields in the first place?

Comment: @dirkgroten You're right, `profile_level` and `profile_type` are null. `site` and `language` are not null. However I can save my form with fields filled like this. The issue seems to provide from `profile` fields. As null and blank field, `unique_together` doesn't work fine. Maybe I have to remove `unique_together` and set the validation in my view ?

Comment: Again, null=True is not the same as blank=True. If you allow null values, they are not taken into account in a unique_together clause. Empty strings are. So if you want to avoid this issue, remove null=True from your CharFields.